# What is "LASSO aggression"?

Tags: regression, lasso, notation, regularization, application

I found a paper that stated in the methods section that they ran "***LASSO aggression***". At first, I thought it was a funny typo but then I did a Google Search:

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22LASSO+AGGRESSION%22&oq=%22LASSO+AGGRESSION%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5893j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

and found 187 sources mentioning "LASSO aggression"!

Is **LASSO aggression** a thing in some applied areas or is it a very common typo that even *The Lancet* has fell for it?

[Lancet link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3559564)

Comment: Friedman, Jerome, Trevor Hastie, and Robert Tibshirani. The elements of statistical learning. Vol. 1. No. 10. New York: Springer series in statistics, 2001.
Chapter 3.4.2

Comment: That section presents LASSO "regression", not "aggression". Please, have a look at my question.

Comment: Looks like a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at a couple of the papers suggests that the authors mean "regression" but are not native English speakers and thus have used an incorrect word.

[This article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwjemODth_XoAhUZgnIEHY47CG0QFjAEegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fatm.amegroups.com%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F30600%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw1JNPtcVR88J4DeDUVIGeH1) seems to have used standard LASSO regression approaches. The word "aggression" only appears in the abstract, not the main text.

The [Lancet paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3559564) that I found was an unreviewed preprint on a server they maintain, evidently similar to the types of papers found (also unreviewed) on [bioRxiv](https://www.biorxiv.org), so I don't think it's fair to say that The Lancet "fell for it." Both that paper and the first one were from authors in China.

Then again, those who use the 1-standard-error criterion instead of the minimum error criterion for choosing a penalty factor after cross-validation might be accused properly of "LASSO aggression," aggressively removing predictors in a search for parsimony.